# php & mysql: Get the list of database, tables and fields extracted by a query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to extract the list of databases, tables and fields extracted by a query like this having 2 separate databse
DataBase 'customer' containing a table 'register' with list of customers
DataBase 'supplier' containing a table 'register' with list of suppliers

Certain customers are suppliers also and I need to extract 'name' + money in & money out.
In this case (if a customer is a supplier also) they would share the same 'id' key.

```
select
   C.name, C.surname,
   C.balance as MONEY_IN, S.balance as MONEY_OUT
from
   customer.register C, supplier.register S
where
   C.id = S.id
```

what I would like to obtain is a list with `database_name . table_name . field_name` extracted by the query

ie:

```
customer.register.name
customer.register.surname
customer.register.balance
supplier.register.balance
```

Is there a way to get the above list through a php script?

Through (deprecated) `mysql_field_table()` and `mysql_field_name()` I can get the table and field name, but how I can extract the *database name* also?

Comment: Maybe this thread will help you: [enter link description here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76188/get-table-name-from-union-query)

Comment: Did you try [``mysql_db_name``](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-db-name.php)

Comment: Can you give more explicative name of the fields? With this generic sentence will be more confusion.

Comment: Try `SELECT SCHEMA_NAME AS Database FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA`

Comment: @theantomc, you're right. I've replaced the dummy field with a realistic one.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL's `information_schema` database (a fake database in that you can't insert, update, or delete directly) holds this sort of data.

For example

```
 SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
   FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = database()
```

retrieves all the names of tables and columns in the current database.

You can get the current database (the subject of the most resent `USE whatever` operation with `SELECT database()`.

The trouble with getting the column names making up a `SELECT` query is this: The `SELECT` query itself generates a virtual table. So if the columns coming out of the `SELECT` query have the same names as those going into it, you can definitely get their column names. `SELECT * FROM table` generates that kind of result set.

In PDO, `getColumnMeta(column_number)` gives you back some metadata for a result set.  In `mysqli_`, it's `fetch_fields()`.

In your specific case you join two tables from different databases. The metadata can give back table and column names for the columns in the join. But MySQL does not pass along the database name in the result set.

You could use aliases something like this.

```
select  a.field_1 AS db_1_field_1, 
        a.field_2 AS db_1_field_2, 
        b.field_3 AS db_2_field_3
  from  db_1.table_1 a 
  join  db_2.table_2 b ON a.field_9 = b.field_9
```

This has the effect of annotating your column names with the source database. (But it's a hack.)

Comment: in my case the goal is to extract the database, table and field name considering that the query is extracting data from 2 different tables contained in 2 different databases (ie: select * from db1.table1, db2.table2 where table1.field = table2.field). So database() would get me the "used" database that may not be part of the query.